# Where to download a fixed DSDT?

Tags: bios, acpi

I have an older PC I'm trying to throw Ubuntu on.  It's running an Abit NF M2 Nview and the DSDT is buggy even on the latest bios.  Everywhere I look at says to download fixed DSDT's from this site:

http://acpi.sourceforge.net/dsdt/view.php

But it doesn't appear to work any longer.  This was a fairly popular mobo so I'm hoping fixed DSDT's existed.  Right now the system crashes shortly after booting if I don't use acpi=off in the boot options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new site is [lesswatts.org](https://lesswatts.org/projects/acpi/), which is supported by [Intel Corporation](https://lesswatts.org/aboutotc.php). However, they don't seem to have archived the downloads that were formerly available on sourceforge. They also don't seem to be available if the old pages are viewed in [the internet archive](http://wayback.archive.org/web/%2a/http://acpi.sourceforge.net/dsdt/view.php).

At [lesswatts.org](https://lesswatts.org/projects/acpi/) they explain that

> In the early days of Linux/ACPI, DSDT modifications were common to work around both BIOS bugs and Linux bugs. However, the stated goal of the Linux/ACPI project today is that Linux should run on un-modified firmware. Thus, the DSDT database at the old http://acpi.sourceforge.net web site is now largely a historical artifact.

However, there is some useful information on the site about [debugging your ACPI problems](https://lesswatts.org/projects/acpi/utilities.php) and [overriding your current dsdt](https://lesswatts.org/projects/acpi/overridingDSDT.php). It will, however, be necessary to compile your own kernel to incorporate your own modified DSDT.

You will need the `acpidump` package* and the Intel 'ASL compiler/decompiler' known as `iasl` in a package of the same name. The process of dumping the ACPI data into ASCII file with `acpidump`, the conversion of that data to binary with `acpixtract`, and then the `iasl` decompiling, user modifications, and `iasl` recompiling is explained well [on the lesswatts site.](https://lesswatts.org/projects/acpi/overridingDSDT.php)

The [lesswatts mailing-lists](https://lesswatts.org/projects/acpi/mailing-lists.php) may contain information on your motherboard, but I couldn't seem to find any exact references, but it worth looking on other hardware specific mailing lists.

*The `acpidump` package in Ubuntu is known upstream as `pm-tools`.